# mysql slow select query, tried every optimization trick I know!

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, performance

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    `date`,
    al.cost,
    SUM(l.bnd) AS bnd,
    l.type,
    count(*) AS amount
FROM alogs AS al
    INNER JOIN logs AS l ON al.logid = l.id
WHERE 
    aid = 0 AND
    l.`date` >= '2010-01-17' AND
    l.`date` <= '2011-04-19'
GROUP BY l.`date`, l.type
```

logs counts 5 million rows
alogs counts 4.3 million rows
execution time is about 90 seconds.

I have:
a primary key on logs.id (auto inc)
an index (BTREE) on logs.date
an index (BTREE) on alogs.logid
an index (BTREE) on alogs.aid

I tried:
- an index (BTREE) on logs.type, but that didn't improve anything (I think because type can only be 2 things)
- a covering index on logs.date and logs.type
- partitioning the logs table per month internally, but with the timespan used above (which covered all partitions) it'd even become slower, can't partition on aid because there are more than 2k different id's
- stripping down functions from the query untill it became fast to see where the problem lies.
I only had to remove the GROUP clause (and the SUM() and count(*) functions to get proper results) and by doing so the execution time went subsecond.
- remove the group clause and group in memory, but the result of over 3 million rows was just too much and would even take longer.

Are there any other things I can do but I don't know of? If so I'd love to hear about it!

Thanks,

lordstyx

EDIT (2011-04-22 11:30)
Here's the EXPLAIN EXTENDED result

```
id| select_type| table| type  | possible_keys| key    | key_len| ref     | rows   | Extra
1 | SIMPLE     | al   | ref   | logid,aid    | adid   | 4      | const   | 3010624| Using temporary; Using filesort
1 | SIMPLE     | l    | eq_ref| PRIMARY,date | PRIMARY| 4      | al.logid| 1      | Using where
```

Comment: How many rows are being selected?

Comment: Oh that really depends on what aid is, but in this case the query returns 168 rows. (Without the group clause this is 3-4mil)

Comment: You didn't post the results of `EXPLAIN` or `EXPLAIN EXTENDED`. Did you try that?

Comment: Edited the post, there you go.

Answer (score 0):

If your date range is a small set of the rows in the log table, you want it to use that index.  You said that you created an index on logs.date, but you need a composite index on (logs.date, logs.id) so mysql doesn't have to read the row off disk to get the id to join to the alogs table.  You'd want an index on alogs(log_id) for the join.

You could probably squeeze out some more by putting the columns fromt he SELECT in the indexes as well, so

```
 logs(date, id, bnd, type)
 alogs(log_id, aid, cost)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The timespan in the first post is the entire date range. When I tried the indexes you suggested it became a second slower. I tried it with a smaller date range (few months) and it still took 85 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

if the `aid` filter cuts out a large portion of rows, something like this would pare down the data that's being joined against:

```
SELECT
    l.`date`,
    sum(al.cost) as cost,
    SUM(l.bnd) AS bnd,
    l.type,
    sum(qty) AS amount
FROM logs AS l
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT logid, sum(cost) as cost, COUNT(*) as qty
    FROM alogs
    WHERE aid = 0
    GROUP BY logid
) al ON al.logid = l.id
GROUP BY l.`date`, l.type
```

Without knowing a little more about the data structure (many `alogs` records per `logs` record?) it's difficult to suggest further improvements. Computing data prior to joins and `GROUP BY` clauses can greatly speed up execution by reducing the total number of rows that need to be processed. Since the query without grouping returns blazingly fast, further indexing and tweaking is unlikely to increase execution speed.

Comment: Very nice, this cuts the time in half. However when I add back in the WHERE clause for a date range it becomes just as slow as it used to be.
There can be 1, 2, 3 or 4 alog records for one log record.